# Cannot publish to SNS from a thread in AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

My lambda function written in .net core is able to publish a message to an SNS topic successfully. However, if I publish the message by creating a new thread `(using Task.Run(() =>)` in the Lambda function, then the thread just hangs when executing the `IAmazonSimpleNotificationService.PublishAsync()` method.
The thread also hangs if I call `IAmazonSimpleNotificationService.ListTopicsAsync(new ListTopicsRequest())`.

So does any new thread launched in AWS Lambda require a specific context?